# Basis of a set of all linear transfotmations from X to Y

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's call $L(X,Y)$ a set of all linear trasformations from $X$ to $Y$. I am looking for it's basis (assuming that $\dim X, \dim Y < +\infty$). My textbook has the basis defined as the set of linear transformations $F_{i,j}: X \rightarrow Y$ such that if $x_1,...,x_n$ is a basis of $X$ and $y_1,...,y_m$ is a basis of $Y$ then:

$$F_{i,j}(x_k)=\delta_{k,j}y_i$$

I think that $\delta_{k,j}$ is Kronecker delta but my textbook doesn't specify that. And that basis makes sense - it's a set of functions that only for one element from basis of $X$ output exactly one element of basis of $Y$ and give $0$ otherwise. But let's continue...

Further, my textbook gives a sample basis for $L(\Bbb{R}^2,\Bbb{R}[t]_2)$ (where $\Bbb{R}[t]_2$ is a set of all polynomials of $t$ with real coefficients). Well, the basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$ is $(1,0)^T, (0,1)^T$ and for $\Bbb{R}[t]_2$ a sample basis would be $1,t,t^2$. And then the textbook gives a sample $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)^T$. And says that a sample basis for $L(\Bbb{R}^2,\Bbb{R}[t]_2)$ would be functions that for $\mathbf{x}$ output:

$F_{1,1}(\mathbf{x})=x_1$, $F_{2,1}(\mathbf{x})=x_1t$, $F_{3,1}(\mathbf{x})=x_1t^2$, $F_{1,2}(\mathbf{x})=x_2$, $F_{2,2}(\mathbf{x})=x_2t$, $F_{3,2}(\mathbf{x})=x_2t^2$

My question is - where is an analogy to the definition here? I thought $F_{i,j}$ should output values only for basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and here it is defined as a function, that outputs something for a vector $\mathbf{x}$. Why?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem, but taking a shot: Set $e_1 = (1,0)^T$ and $e_2 = (0,1)^T$ and compute $F_{i,j}(e_k)$ – can you see the analogy now? The thing is that giving a linear map on a linear space $X$ is the same as specifying it on a basis of $X$. One time the textbook did specify $F_{i,j}$ only on a basis of $X$, the other time it defined $F_{i,j}$ on all of $X$. Does this help you?

Comment: Yup, I think I understand this now, thanks :)